# Azure AD SignOut doesn't work for the multiple Applications. i.e Single SignOut

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have 5 different .Net Core Angular applications which has Same AD Authentication Integrated. I want to implement Single SignOut for all the application. i.e. If I sign-out from one, it should forcefully sign-out user from other applications. Practically this is possible and Azure AD also supports the same. My all other functionality work as expected like login, logout, token retrieval but I am facing challenge with single sign-out functionality.

I configured LogOutUrl at my AD Application and have below code at my application level,

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie()
              .AddOpenIdConnect(options => SetOpenIdConnectOptions(options, services));

private void SetOpenIdConnectOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var __serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"];
        options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"];
        options.CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        };

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
            {
                var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                var identifier = context.Principal.Claims.First(item => item.Type == ClaimTypeLookup.ObjectIdentifier).Value;

                options.SaveTokens = true;


            },
        };
    }

[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

Also, if I logout from my office365 account, there is no effect on my applications. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen my article on the topic: https://joonasw.net/view/aad-single-sign-out-in-asp-net-core?

Comment: yes but o.RemoteSignOutPath blocks my logout feature.

Comment: Did you make the authentication cookie SameSite=None? The remote signout request is done cross-origin so by default the cookie might not be submitted.

Comment: Yes I did. But even adding RemoteSignOutPath blocking my current application signout as well. Without that, my at least my current application is logging out properly.

Comment: @DSA why/how is RemoteSignOutPath blocking your current app signout?

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla: Not sure about exact root cause but I figured out the end to end solution without RemoteSignOutPath and it's working good.

Comment: @DSA that's great to know. BTW I was asking on the consequences or how it affected your current application sign out process.